# Replay timestamped event stream with Reactive Extensions

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I have a collection of items of following class:

```
public class Event
{
    public DateTimeOffset Timestamp;
    public object Data;
}
```

I want to create `IObservable<Event>` where each item is published at the time of `Timestamp` in the future. Is this possible with `Observable.Delay` or do I have to write my own `IObservable<T>` implementation?

I will mention that this structure is something like a log file. There can be tens of thousands of `Event` items, but only 1-2 are to be published per second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While my first answer is working as intended, performance of creating the observable sequence is not ideal with hundreds of thousands of events - you pay substantial initialization cost (order of 10 seconds on my machine).

To improve performance, taking advantage of already sorted nature of my data, I implemented custom `IEnumerable<Event>` that is looping through events, yielding and sleeping between them. With this `IEnumerable` one can easily call `ToObservable<T>` and it works as intended:

```
IObservable<Event> CreateSimulation(IEnumerable<Event> events)
{
     IEnumerable<Event> simulation()
     {
         foreach(var ev in events)
         {
             var now = DateTime.UtcNow;

             if(ev.Timestamp > now)
             {
                 Thread.Sleep(ev.Timestamp - now);
             }

             yield return ev;          
        }
    }

    return simulation().ToObservable();
}
```

Answer (score 6):

It turns out it's very simple to do with `Observable.Delay` overload taking variable time:

```
//given IEnumerable<Event> events:
var observable = events.ToObservable().Delay(ev => Observable.Timer(ev.Timestamp));
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the Rx library lacks a mechanism for converting an `IEnumerable<T>` to an `IObservable<T>`, by enumerating it lazily and time shifting its elements. Below is a custom implementation. The idea is to `Zip` the source enumerable with a subject, and control the enumeration by sending `OnNext` notifications to the subject at the right moments.

```
/// <summary>Converts an enumerable sequence to a time shifted observable sequence,
/// based on a time selector function for each element.</summary>
public static IObservable<T> ToObservable<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> source,
    Func<T, DateTimeOffset> dueTimeSelector,
    IScheduler scheduler = null)
{
    scheduler ??= Scheduler.Default;
    return Observable.Defer(() =>
    {
        var subject = new BehaviorSubject<Unit>(default);
        return subject
            .Zip(source, (_, x) => x)
            .Delay(x => Observable.Timer(dueTimeSelector(x), scheduler))
            .Do(_ => subject.OnNext(default));
    });
}
```

The [`BehaviorSubject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/reactive-extensions/hh211949(v=vs.103)) has been chosen because it has an initial value, and so it sets the wheels in motion naturally.

The `Observable.Defer` operator is used to prevent multiple subscriptions from sharing the same state (the `subject` in this case), and interfering with each other. More info about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64843343/how-to-bind-a-non-disposable-object-with-each-subscription-of-a-cold-observable).

Usage example:

```
IEnumerable<Event> events = GetEvents();

IObservable<Event> observable = events.ToObservable(x => x.Timestamp);
```